# How can i perform a build on ec2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian

I have a fresh ec2 instance and im trying to install appscale tools and then appscale itself. When i go to do the build, i get an error says lsb_release: command not found.

Its my understanding that this command is pretty standard in linux. So is there a way to get ec2 to run it?

Comment: What is your linux distribution ? Paste the output of  $cat /etc/*release here.

Comment: no such file or directory. However, i got past this step but installing a redhat distro to aid in the build. Now when i run the build i get the error "n/a is not supported" which is the worst error message of all time.

Comment: All i need to do is deploy appscale 1.11.0 (an old release that supports GAE py 2.5) and deploy our app. Time is critical. can you give me an avenue to look into as google has turned up *nothing* on that error, or suggest a way to make a GAE py25 app continue to live happy as GAE wants py27 and we cannot rebuild it at this time.

Comment: I think this is happenning because yum installed a redhat distro when im running AMI. i used yum provides */lsb_release . Perhaps its an incompatibility thing? If so, whats the way to removed that package and install the correct module for running lsb_release